# not able to use delay for more than two times in function .displaying only last output

Tags: java, android, button, delay

i am using a function named onmode() to change bacground color of button to red and then using delay to change it to green,but when i use two delays in function it does not show the effect of first delay() .why it is so,although it is going through whole function? 
it does not show timer1 but directly timer2 in text field.
thanks
 package com.example.countdown;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView text1;

    CountDownTimer counter;
    Button option1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colorb);

        onmode();
    }

    public void timer() { // function for delaying
        counter = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                option1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

            public void onFinish() {

                option1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }.start();

    }

    public void onmode() {

        timer();

        text1.setText("timer1");
        timer();

        text1.setText("timer2");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: these are not blocking calls. Timer() 2 does NOT wait for timer 1 to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You start the first timer, set the text to "timer1", then immediately start the second timer and set the text to "timer2". The timers run on separate threads, so your code will not wait for one timer to finish before starting the second one. There will be at most a few milliseconds between the time the timers start, and they will be calling their `onTick` and `onFinish` methods virtually in sync with one another.

If the "timer1" text is displayed at all (there may not even be a repaint before the text is replaced with "timer2", it will only be there for the blink of an eye before being replaced by "timer2". It is almost impossible that the human eye would be able to detect it before it has changed.

Additionally, since the two timers have the exact same effect (setting a UI element to red once per second, then setting it to green when the time is up), there is no way to visually distinguish which timer last affected the display.

If you really want the timers to run one after the other, you could start the second timer from the `onFinish` method of the first timer.